# Xcode archive - no app store distribution profile

Tags: xcode, upload, submit

I want to upload an app to the AppStore: Product --> Archive. But there is no **"Submit to the iOS App Store"** option, only:

1. Save built product
2. Export as Xcode archive

Why isn't there an option? It's the first time I've encountered this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have configured all linked libraries with "Skip Install" to "YES" in the build settings screen. Also you can click "Validate" to find potential problems

Comment: Yes, and then there are only two options, not three, submit to ios app store is missing

Comment: Have you generated Distribution certificate and provisioning profile ?

Comment: Make sure you have configured all linked libraries with "Skip Install" to "YES" in the build settings screen. Also you can click "Validate" to find potential problems

Comment: @Oleg you are a lifesaver. I was about to throw my laptop after rebuilding my project for the 10th time